# JavaFX tooling is disabled

Tags: java, javafx

I installed JavaFX for eclipse as a plug-in and after downloading it I received this error message:

```
You are not running your eclipse instance with Java8.
The JavaFX tooling is disabled because of this.
Make Java8 the default system java or
adjust your eclipse.ini to pass -vm pointing to your Java8 install.

In case you want to turn off this check open your preferences and go to General > Startup and Shutdown and uncheck 'JavaFX Tooling Java Check'
```

I am using the jdk-16.

Any idea why it is not working for me?

Comment: update eclipse or its tooling?

Answer (score 0):

Update each piece of your tool chain.

The style of the reported Java version number changed since Java 8. This breaks some tools that expect only the older version number format.

See [*JEP 223: New Version-String Scheme*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/223).